# Is there a way to define the value of the index in an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, integer

I had an assignment due today ( its late already so i wont be getting credit for this but the problem is eating at me) that I could not figure out for the life of me. The assignment goes as followed: withoutTen: Return a version of the given array where all the 10's have been removed.
                The remaining elements should shift left towards the start of the array as needed,
                and the empty spaces at the end of the array should be 0.
                So {1, 10, 10, 2} yields {1, 2, 0, 0}.
                You may modify and return the given array or make a new array.

```
            withoutTen({1, 10, 10, 2}) --> {1, 2, 0, 0}
            withoutTen({10, 2, 10}) --> {2, 0, 0}
            withoutTen({1, 99, 10}) --> {1, 99, 0}
```

I have tried various things to make the program work but failed.

`

// The arraylist is already defined to an Integer class with a name of list

```
    int i= 0;
    //loop
    for(i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        if( list.get(i) == 10)
        {
             list.remove(i);
             list.add(0);
        }
     }
     return list;
```

`
This shows the right result {1,2,0,0} but that is the only one. Can anyone explain to me if there is a way to change the value of the index if it equals 10 and send it to the back of the line as a 0?

Comment: shouldn't it be `list.remove(i)` instead of `1` ?

Comment: Don't worry I still confuse i and 1 in my code once in a while. Next time try understanding the output, this will help you debug your applications faster. And btw, it is good practice to initialize your variable i directly in your for loop declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do

```
int nbOccur = Collections.frequency(yourList, 10);
yourList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(10));
yourList.addAll(Collections.nCopies(nbOccur, 0));
```

- Get the number of occurences(n) of 10.
- Remove them all.
- Add a List that contains n times 0.

---

A one liner with Java 8 would be

```
yourList.stream()
        .filter(i -> i != 10)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .addAll(Collections.nCopies(Collections.frequency(yourList, 10), 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically - you treat it as a copy process where you walk a `from` and a `to` up the array making sure `from` skips `10` whenever it sees it.

```
public int[] withoutTen(int[] a) {
    // Where we are copying to.
    int to = 0;
    // Where we are copying from.
    int from = 0;
    // Zero padding at the end so carry on 'till to gets there.
    while (to < a.length) {
        // Skip all 10s.
        while (from < a.length && a[from] == 10) {
            // Skip it.
            from += 1;
        }
        // Copy it (or 0 if we're past the end).
        a[to++] = from < a.length ? a[from++] : 0;
    }
    return a;
}

public void test() {
    int[][] tests = new int[][]{
        {1, 10, 10, 2},
        {10, 2, 10},
        {1, 99, 10}
    };
    for (int[] a : tests) {
        System.out.println("\t" + Arrays.toString(a) + " -> " + Arrays.toString(withoutTen(a)));
    }

}
```

prints

```
[1, 10, 10, 2] -> [1, 2, 0, 0]
[10, 2, 10] -> [2, 0, 0]
[1, 99, 10] -> [1, 99, 0]
```

Equivalent using `for` loop is a little tidier:

```
public int[] withoutTen(int[] a) {
    // Zero padding at the end so carry on 'till to gets there.
    for (int to = 0, from = 0; to < a.length; to++, from++) {
        // Skip all 10s.
        while (from < a.length && a[from] == 10) {
            // Skip it.
            from += 1;
        }
        // Copy it (or 0 if we're past the end).
        a[to] = from < a.length ? a[from] : 0;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not fully understand Java syntax. I do not say that to feel smug, but the code probably does not do what you think it does. Review your Java syntax knowledge and then try again. :-)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon While I agree, He doesn't have enought rep to comment.

Comment: @ OldCurmudgeon Sorry, new guy here :-) Will know in the future.

Comment: @JiříKantor - Actually it was my mistake - I should have checked your points value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to worry about the data space complexity ? if yes then -- obviously you can do better --but this should work for your purpose..

psudo code

```
List<Integer> beforeList = Arrays.asList(1,10,10,0,2);

//create array
int[] myFinalArray = new int[beforeList.size]()
int arrayIdx =0;
for (Integer i : beforeList){
   if (i != 10){
         myFinalArray[arrayIdx++ ] = i;
   }
}
//print/return your finalArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the help, it seems that my code was almost correct but i did have my list.get() method wrong. I had placed a (1) instead of (i) which in fact caused me a lot of pain and errors. `for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++)
        {
            if(list.get(i)==10)
            {
                list.remove(i);
                list.add(0);
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer for this

```
public int[] withoutTen(int[] nums) {

   if (nums == null) {
    return nums;
  }

  int non10pos = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {

    if (nums[i] != 10) {
      int temp = nums[i];
      nums[i] = nums[non10pos];  // move the non-zero number to position i
      nums[non10pos] = temp;  // move the non-10 number toward the front
      ++non10pos;
    }
    else{
      nums[i] = 0;
    }


  }

  return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution passes all the tests:

```
public int[] withoutTen(int[] nums) {
  if (nums.length == 0) {
    return nums;
  }
  
  int[] withoutTen = new int[nums.length];
  int counter = 0;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < withoutTen.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] != 10) {
      for (int j = counter; j < withoutTen.length; j++) {
        withoutTen[j] = nums[i];
        break;
      }
      counter++;
    }
  }
  
  return withoutTen;
}
```